# JS fetch + php codeigniter4 CORS issue

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, cors, codeigniter-4

I'm using vue3 with codeigniter4 .I am getting a CORS issue with fetch When sending a custom header even I set what should be set for CORS in server side method (Without using the framework filters ,Just pure php)

my js code is :

```js
GetMyOrders() {
            fetch(this.AppMainData.ApiUrl+'orders/get', {
                   method: 'GET',
                   headers:{
                    'Role': 'some role',
                    }
                }).then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    console.log(data);
                    this.MyOrders = data.result;
                    this.explode;
                    return;

                })
        }
```

And my php code in codeigniter controller (Not resource) is :

```js
public function GetMyOrders(){
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Role ,Content-Type,Origin');
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true');
            $db=\Config\Database::connect();
            $data['result']=$db->query("Some SQL Query")->getResult();
         return json_encode($data);
        }
```

The fetch is successful when not fetching with header , but when i add my custom header the response is blocked by CORS policy as bellow:

"Access to fetch at 'http://localhost/MyApp/public/api/orders/get' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

Any idea please (Without using External Solutions) !!!

Comment: if you add a `catch` to the `fetch` chain are there any errors being logged?

Comment: You need to have a handler for OPTION request. For a cross domain / port ajax call, the browser will do a pre-flight request (as in your error report) with the request method as OPTION. You should have at least one URL to handle OPTION request and respond with CORS header and then you will be all set!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS: PHP: Response to preflight request doesn't pass. Am allowing origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44479681/cors-php-response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-am-allowing-origin)

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius honestly ,i didn't but i will try and see

Comment: @RakeshMehta i think what u said is right (that's what reached when i was seeking a lot for the reason) but the problem i don't have clear idea about pre-flight request and how to deal with, should i only modify code in php ?or or modify on both js and php?

Comment: @Jelmergu i think i may help .. i will take a deep look and feedback the result

Comment: You just need a route something like   `$routes->option('(.*)', static function () {
     //return an empty response with cors headers
});`

Comment: I did it .. in Routes.php 

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
              if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']) &&
                   $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')  {
                header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
                header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Role,Origin ,Refer , Content-Type');
              }
              exit;
            }

Comment: thank u so much guys ..finally solved .. i have to may more checks for the reauest but in general it worked with no trouble  i should read more about preflights

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's solved .As the Bros mentioned in replies (A preflight request issue)
Just adding this checking Request Code in (Routes.php)  And The problem is solved

```js
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']) &&
       $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')  {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Role,Origin , Content-Type');
  }
  exit;
}
```

Thank U Guys