# EditorJS upload file to php server failes on CORS

Tags: php, editorjs

I'm trying to allow an user to upload a file using EditorJS (client side) to my file server. The goal is that an user will upload a file in the editor, which will be sent to the file server, which saves the file, generates a file name and returns this in the following format, to which editorjs will automatically add it to its content:

```
{
  "success": 1, 
  "file": {
    "url": "http://whatever.the/url-should-be.png"
  }
}
```

So for this I created a PHP script on my server that will recieve the image, process it to check if there are no errors / exceeded filesized.

The file is sent to the server as `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` with the file as value name `file`. I tested the file upload on Insomnia with these exact parameters and headers, which responds with a beautiful `201 Created` code, and responds with the full URL.

For testing purposes I've added the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to the file server.

*EDIT:* Header added on the `uploadByFile.php` using

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Now queue the problem I'm facing. When using EditorJS to upload the file, the request failes for some reason on CORS.

The config for my `@editorjs/image` is as follows:

```
{
    image: {
        class: Image,
        config: {
            endpoints: {
                byFile: 'https://cdn.appomgeving.nl/api/editorjs/uploadByFile.php',
            },
            field: 'file'
        }
    },
}
```

EditorJS first sends a preflight which has status `200` which shows the server response headers has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` as well.

Yet the xhr request from EditorJS returns a status `CORS error` with the following text:
`Cross-Origin Resource Sharing error: HeaderDisallowedByPreflightResponse`

I've googled the error, but all sites say you have to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin, which is set on my site.

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix this?

(for people who would like to reproduce the problem, link above is open for public, so can be accessed)

Comment: Using `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` within `uploadByFile.php`

Comment: The error seems to be about headers. There may be a header in the request which isn't allowed by default in a CORS request. You'd have to add an Access-Control-Allow-Headers response header as well in the PHP, and specify what additional request headers are permitted.

Comment: The error is saying your request includes an unexpected request header. Is there any more to the error message indicating which header that might be? Check the request headers using your browser's dev tools _Network_ panel

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers for more info

Comment: Also, sending a `multipart/form-data` POST request should not require a pre-flight. Again, the reason it does in this case seems to be extra headers.

Comment: The only odd header I can find would be `X-Requested-With`

Comment: @Tim well there's your problem. Can you remove or prevent that request header?

Comment: From the duplicate, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61856861/283366). You'll want to add `X-Requested-With` to the list of allowed headers and also respond to preflight `OPTIONS` requests appropriately

Comment: Oh wow you're right! That header is indeed the problem. I can't remove or prevent that header because it's sent by default with editorjs, but i've added the the header `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With` to the file server